# Receive browser notifications in Flutter Webview

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How do you handle website notifications, the ones that say "Allow receiving notifications", even when the app is in background or killed? I've been searching for a solution for hours but almost all of results talk about Firebase FCM.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter WebView when is showing in the app, it's the same way to do as normal as getting firebase messaging package and hit message with specified token.

Here is the package: [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)

Flutter WebView is nohing to do with browser notifications.
Hope it helps!